# Writing a query using ActiveRecord using multiple relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the relations listed below, I am trying to write an active record query that would return a list of `Sections` from a given student_id like:

```
  def self.student_courses(student_id)
    Section
        .where(enrollment: Enrollment
        .where(student: Student.find_by(student_id: student_id)))
  end
```

but this throws an error: `SQLException: no such column: sections.enrollment:`

which I understand, there isn't a column with that name in Sections. how should I write the query to return a list of `Sections?` for a given student?

[image: ERD]

**Section**

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments
  belongs_to :course
```

**Enrollment**

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student
end
```

**Student**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :sections, through: :enrollments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't prefix the primary key columns in Rails. Just name them `id` - which the the Rails convention - and I would say that in general prefixing is a superflous and a solution to the non-problem of writing crappy SQL with ambiguous identifiers.

Rails is all about convention over configuration and using non-conventional column names would require you to specify the primary key column in all your associations etc.

While it [can be done](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) in the case of a legacy application don't make your life difficult and app crappy by doing it new code.

Once you have rectified the issues by renaming the PKs accessing the associated records is as simple as:

```
Section.joins(:students).where(students: { id: x })
# or
Section.joins(:enrollment).where(enrollment: { student_id: x })
# or
student = Student.eager_load(:sections).find(x)
student.sections
```